# VS debugger attaches when my program crashes... but not before?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I wrote a program (well, a native C++ dll loaded by a third party app).

When (alas) it crashes, VS automatically attaches to the app, loads symbols for the dll and allows me to do a post mortem.

But if I try to attach the debugger before it crashes, it doesn't load symbols for the dll (which is definitely loaded and running at the time).  It doesn't even *try* to load symbols for the dll in fact.

How can this be?  What might be configured differently between the automatic debugger attachment and the manual one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, quick answer.  In the VS Attach to Process dialog, I needed to select "Attach to: -> [Select...]" and check "Native code".   Doh.